# Big O-notation and series

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation

While there are many questions regarding Big O-notation and in particular, its usage when it comes to series, none fit my question perfectly: possibly because I am so unfamiliar with the notation.

Consider an algorithm where the number of operations needed increases by $29n^3 + 48n + 1932$. If I have undestood it correctly, one simply writes that the algorithm runs at $O(n^3)$. While my explanation here might be sloppy, its not that relevant: the main point is that $n^3$ is the dominant term.

Consider the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{999n}$. We can confirm the divergence of this series by one of the many tests taught Calculus 2. However, is it ever sufficient to point out that "the sequence decreases approximately as $\frac{1}{n}$" or "decreases at a rate of $O(\frac{1}{n})$"?

Answer (score 2):

The series does not decrease (the partial sums do increase, to infinity); but I reckon what you are trying to say is that its general term $a_n$ is $\Omega\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$, meaning that there exists a constant $\alpha > 0$ such that asymptotically (for any $n$ "big enough") $a_n \geq \alpha\cdot\frac{1}{n}$.

This is what captures the divergence of the series; saying that the general term is $O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$ is *not* what you want, as it does not imply the series diverges (for instance, $\frac{1}{n^2}$ or even $0$ are also $O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$).

Comment: Thanks, I meant the sequence $a_n$, yes. I can't say that I understand it completely, but that's my fault for not reading up on the notation. I'll come back to you in a few weeks when exams have passed and, likely, accept your answer.

Comment: Good luck with the exam! As a rough first approximation, when confronted to them you can always read the $O(\cdot)$, $\Omega(\cdot)$ and  $\Theta(\cdot)$ as "at most", "at least" and "equivalent to" (forgetting about the constants, and the asymptoticity). This gives you a good sense of what is going on.

Comment: Yes, we actually don't use any of that notation in the course, I'm just looking for new ways to view the material, as I genuinely dislike the way series are being taught (give the student 6-7 tests and train them to memorize which tests fit which series.) EDIT: Reading through your comment again, that notation will prove very useful at the exam, seeing as our Prof is of the "use any method you like"-school.

Answer (score 1):

If $a_n=O(b_n)$ and $\sum |a_n|$ diverges, then $\sum |b_n|$ also diverges.

To see this, use the very definition of $O$ : there exists $N$ and $M$ such that $n \geq N \Rightarrow |a_n|\leq M |b_n|$ and then sum inequalities starting from $n=N$.

In the specific case where $a_n$ and $b_n$ are positive, if $a_n=O(b_n)$ and $\sum a_n$ diverges, then $\sum b_n$ also diverges.